# codeigniter with same route name with different controller functions

Tags: codeigniter, controller, routes

I want to keep routes like this

```
   $route["signup"] = "Controller/signup";
   $route["signup"] ="Controller2/fbsignup";
```

Is it possible to to give same route names with different controller functions.
Then how ?

Comment: No, you can't do like this

Comment: how to face this type of overides @Abdulla

Comment: you can't override this, just replace is there `$route["signup"]` and `$route["fbsignup"]`

Comment: not working what ?

Comment: i have page signup, in that i have button to facebook.If i given like that its not working.If i given website/fbsignup then working but not working in website/signup

Comment: You can't do that.Just think of one URL with two different location, that is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.
If you write same route again, it will overwrite first one.
It is just like an array variable.
If you assign any other value to variable, first one will overwrite.

But you can specify HTTP method with route.

Comment: second one will overwrite not first one

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do like this, you are going to make api then define method that will help

> $route["signup"]["post"] = "Controller/signup";
>      $route["signup"]["GET"] ="Controller2/fbsignup";

Comment: If I say this is wrong would you agree with me?? and **talk properly *(be nice to others)***

Comment: i agreed so that y iam asking how to face@Abdulla

Comment: that comment for him, not you. I've added a comment on your question check that

Comment: if you are going at restapi then follow it
https://github.com/parthgodhani/codeigniter-restserver

Comment: function declaration 
function1_get()   //it will run with get method
function1_post() //it will run with post methos

Answer (score 0):

I want to keep routes like this

```
   $route["signup"] = "Controller/signup";
   $route["signup"] ="Controller2/fbsignup";
```

then try this in routes and url should be like signup/signup and signup/fbsignup

```
   $route["signup/signup"] = "Controller/signup";
   $route["signup/fbsignup"] ="Controller2/fbsignup";
```

call the url like

```
signup/signup
signup/fbsignup
```

Comment: Give the urls you are using to output

Comment: my problem is one page with two functions i need to call

Comment: just give the urls to check